# What are diferent reflection percentages of different colors?

Tags: visible-light, waves, reflection

I don't need any accurate answer. Suppose reflection percentage for white is 100% (which is not even true for mirrors) then what will it be like for different colours like violet, green and red etc of the same material from which white is made.

Comment: Assume 100% reflection for white.  Assume 50% reflection for blue. Can one material do both?

Comment: Thanks. Yes we can't call it material but I got the answer.

Comment: http://www.olympusmicro.com/primer/photomicrography/images/bwfilters/typicalspectra.jpg

Answer (score 0):

White is not a color. It means "all colors have the same amount". So "N% of reflection for white" means, by definition, N% for any peculiar color (with color meaning "each pure physical color as in the rainbow").